# Getting the versioning through maven API

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm trying to get the versions of a maven artifact by using:

```
@Mojo(name = "myGoal", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.VERIFY) 
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo{

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true)
    private MavenProject project;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {

        Artifact myartifact = project.getArtifact();

        ArtifactRepositoryMetadata artifactRepoMetadata = new ArtifactRepositoryMetadata(myartifact);
        Versioning versioning = artifactRepoMetadata.getMetadata().getVersioning();
        List<Version> versions = versioning.getVersions();
```

But for some reason "versioning" is null. What do I need to do to get it to work and return the versioning so that I can get a list of versions for my artifact?

Comment: What about using [versions-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) already does this?